# Passing parameters from TAC for job execution

Tags: talend

I have a job that is quite generic and differing parameters are passed as context parameters from different files. But i still need to "hardcode" the context
file name and create multiple jobs in TAC (Talend Administration Console) for execution. What i was hoping to do is use a generic job and pass the context file to be used to that job 
from TAC. Then as part of job execution the context file that is being passed in would be read and context loaded.
My question is how can i achieve that, basically passing different context files from TAC based on execution times?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One approach might be to surround the generic job with multiple wrapper jobs that contain the contexts (or links to the appropriate context files) in them and pass these context variables to the generic child job.

This would work well if you have some generic functionality that is needed by several different jobs but would want different data passing to them or want data presented in different ways to them.

If you then changed the logic of the generic job then all of your wrapper jobs would use the new logic straight away.

Of course, if you have an Enterprise licence (which you do if you have access to the TAC) a better alternative to this is joblets which are designed for this very purpose and can be used to completely change the data sources/targets and just keep the logic separated out.

Alternatively you can use the TAC to pass custom context variables on demand. To do this click on the task in the job conductor and then press the "Context parameters" button at the bottom (next to triggers). Here you can hard code whatever values you want.

I tend to use this for jobs where I have a default context variable set up for most runs but occasionally want to tweak things at run time. So I might have a context variable that allows for filtering of my data and I have this defaulted to all. At run time I can then select my filter criteria context variable and tell it what to filter on for this execution.

Comment: Also you can override the contexts in the execution plan as well. The execution plan uses your overriden context variables, that can be overriden again.

Comment: @BalazsGunics This is going completely off topic but I've yet to see a reason why to use an execution plan rather than wrapping the jobs I would use in a parent wrapper job that then calls those jobs (potentially parallelised too). If you can give me a good, quick example usage then I'd be happy to write a canonical question for you to answer in more detail.

Comment: First I have to tell that I hate the execution plans as well. I recently discovered that you can override the context parameters there as well. So for example, if you have a generic job that moves data between 2 systems, you can have an execution plan created, where first execution loads schema A + table (...), second execution loads schema B + table (...) This way you define the source-target parameters once, then for each execution you can have the execution parameters defined in the execution plan.  So you don't have to open Studio. For DWH jobs we use jobs instead of exec plans

Comment: Thanks guys for your suggestions and insights. Things to consider are ,if i create one job but multiple records in TAC, each being passed a different context file (from which context values for that job will be read), that creates a bunch of similar jobs in TAC. Another option is feeding those context variables in a database, then running the job every 20 mins seeing what jobs have scheduled time less than or equal to the run time, running the returned records in a loop;  i have to see how the jobs can be executed in parallel instead of serially..
Any suggestions or insights?

Comment: Is there any real problem with having lots of similar jobs on the TAC? Your suggested approach sounds overly complicated and prone to issues when things start going wrong.

Comment: @user1486984 You can read the parameters from a database then use flowToIterate to trigger the jobs with different parameters. If you check the "Iterate" link there's an option that enables paralellization. So you can: read the contexts from DB, and then executes the jobs in parallel/serial.

Comment: thanks @BalazsGunics and ydaetskcoR for your suggestions, will try to implement and post back on the maintenance effort of the same.